# Obtener año según número de semana a partir de una fecha

Tags: php, date

Estoy intentando obtener el año y semana de una fecha con formato 'yyyy-mm-dd', por ejemplo '2021-01-01' y con este código lo logro:

```
$date = new DateTime('2021-01-01');
$week = $date->format("W");
$year = reset(explode('-', '2021-01-01'));
```

Y el resultado es semana 53 del año 2021, el problema es que ese día en particular pertenece a la semana 53 del año 2020, no a la semana 1 del año 2021.

**Necesito que el resultado sea año 2020 semana 53.**

¿Como podría hacer la excepción en este caso??

Comment: Que timezone tienes?

Comment: El timezone es America/Chihuahua

Comment: Mi problema es con el año, no con la semana, la semana si esta bien,aunque el día pertenece al año 2021, la semana 53 pertenece al año 2020.

Comment: ¿Es un impedimento el hacer uso de una librería? en php tienes una llamada carbon https://carbon.nesbot.com/ con esa te quitas muchos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Si con tu solución, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener el año que corresponde al número de la semana necesitas usar el [caracter de formato `o`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)

> Año según el número de la semana ISO-8601. Esto tiene el mismo valor que Y, excepto que si el número de la semana ISO (W) pertenece al año anterior o siguiente, se usa ese año en su lugar. (añadido en PHP 5.1.0)

Ejemplo:

```
$date = new DateTime('2021-01-01');
$week = $date->format("W");
$year = $date->format("o");
echo 'Año: ' . $year . ' - Semana: ' . $week;

// Salida: Año: 2020 - Semana: 53
```